# SSL Not working with apache and cloudflare

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have Create SSL certificate using "Let's Encrypt" in Ubantu 18.10 .i follow below documentation to create SSL certificate.

https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates/

I have check SSL certificate was successfully created I have used below command to test it.

openssl verify chain.pem
openssl verify -CAfile chain.pem cert.pem

But Site not working getting 525 error.In cloudflare ""Universal SSL is Active "

Anyone please suggest possible solution to fix this Issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. there is issue with apache config file.I have change port "443"
in apache config file and its working fine.

Thanks